Exporting PostGIS Raster Data to GeoTIFF using gdal_translate - Selecting Subdataset Issue
I am trying to export a PostgreSQL table containing raster data to a GeoTIFF file using gdal_translate.
I am looking for assistance on how to specify the subdataset in the gdal_translate command when dealing with raster data stored in a PostgreSQL database.
My command is as follows:
gdal_translate -of GTiff PG:"host=dem-db port=5432 dbname=dem user=postgres password=passwd" output.tif

However, I encountered the following error: "Input file contains subdatasets. Please, select one of them for reading." Could someone please guide me on how to select one subdataset for exporting to the GeoTIFF file?
I also tried the solution in this link that they recommended sds but it seems one of the datasets is corrupted and as the result this command doesn't work at all. [ I can not delete this dataset ]
Also I couldn't find anything useful in the Gdal doc .
Thank you in advance!

You probably have multiple tables in that database, so it wants you to specify which one you want. PostGIS documentation shows an example of that:
gdal_translate \
    -of PNG \
    -outsize 10% 10% \
    "PG:dbname=db table=tbl" \
    foo.png

Add a table=your_table_goes_here into the src_dataset parameter. In your case:
gdal_translate \
    -of GTiff \
    PG:"host=dem-db port=5432 dbname=dem user=postgres password=passwd table=your_table_goes_here" \
    output.tif


Thank you.
I added table=table_name to my scr_dataset but still got the same error as before

@Alirezasherkatmaesum What do you get if you select r_raster_column from raster_columns where r_table_name='your_table_name'; or select column_name from information_schema.columns where udt_name='raster' and table_name='your_table_name';? You could try to alter table yourtablename rename column the_column_with_your_raster to rast; - I think most tools use that column name as default

I don't think this works either bc my column name is already rast.

@Alirezasherkatmaesum What about the two checks? Those are meant to show how many raster-type columns you have in that specific table; the idea is that gdal_raster could be reporting this error if it finds multiple, based on the type alone, skipping the default column name selection. I won't be able to reproduce this until tomorrow, but if gdal_translate does in fact ignore the default name when it discovers there are multiple columns of the type, you could try to temporarily split off/move or re-type the other raster columns to remove the collision.

It also seems like it might help to add a column named rid: alter table your_table add column rid integer default 1;. The tool seems to rely heavily on undocumented assumptions, and older questions seem to indicate the doc sometimes lags behind latest changes, not always reflecting the current behaviour. I'd be surprised if that was the source of ambiguity causing the error but you could also try to add schema=schema_where_your_table_is into the PG: parameter if somehow it's seeing multiple tables with that name and instead of following search_path behaviour, refuses to pick one.

Thank you.
I will try to move the table away from the others so that there is only one subdataset.
as for you second comment i already tried it. the command seems to ignore the table or schema parameters in the PG: parameter.
The official documentation seems to be incomplete. do you know any other place i can read up on GDAL library?
